# NavigationSplitView column visibilty does not work on iPhone

Tags: swiftui, navigationsplitview

I have a two column NavigationSplitView with a linked NavigationSplitViewVisibility variable. On the iPad everything works as expected. Tapping on the “Go to Detail View” in the sidebar will go to the Detail view. However on the iPhone nothing happens.
Any ideas how to resolve this.
Thanks
Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var visibility:NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView( columnVisibility:$visibility) {
            Text("Go to Detail View" )
                .onTapGesture {
                    visibility = .detailOnly
                }
        } detail: {
            Text( "Show Sidebar")
                .onTapGesture {
                    visibility = .all
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`NavigationSplitView` doesn't show multiple columns in an iPhone, apart from  larger ones (e.g iPhone 14 Pro Max) in landscape.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview)

> On watchOS and tvOS, and with narrow sizes **like on iPhone** or on iPad in Slide Over, the navigation split view collapses all of its columns into a stack, and shows the last column that displays useful information. … For rows in a list that have NavigationLink instances, the list draws disclosure chevrons while in the collapsed state.

If you use `NavigationLink`s in the `sidebar`, the `NavigationSplitView` on an iPhone works just like a regular `NavigationStack`. On larger devices the contents of `detail` is only displayed when no link is selected.

In the example below, tapping the "Hide sidebar" button would do nothing, so I've added a `horizontalSizeClass` `Environment` variable, which allows the button to be hidden on smaller devices.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let names = ["Fred", "Joe", "Bill"]
    
    @State var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NavigationLink(name, destination: Text(name))
                }
                
                if horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
                    Button("Hide sidebar") {
                        withAnimation {
                            visibility = .detailOnly
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select a name")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I was expecting more control in the same way you have with UISplitViewController.